# why const_cast is creating two values for one variable

Tags: c++, const-cast

I was reading about const_cast, as it is supposed to remove the constantness of the variable,

```
const int c1 = 100;
int *c2 = const_cast <int *>(&c1); // removing the constantness
*c2 = 200; // hence now i can edit it
cout << *c2 << endl; // reflect the changed value = 200
cout << c1 << endl; // still old value = 100
```

constantness is removed and variable i can edit, it is same like passing it to some function, which receives "int *" datatype,

but why same pointed space is showing two values?

Is const_cast is creating some other temporary space?

Comment: Undefined behaviour.

Comment: Since `c1` is declared `const`, the compiler knows it can't change. So when it compiles the code `cout << c1`, it optimizes that to `cout << 100`.

Comment: Take a look at the generated assembly code to see what's happening.

Comment: Oh Okay, yes seems correct, because i am trying to modify a constant variable. Which is in compilers hand to behave.